# How to identify either the mask/edge detection of an image is Circle or Oval shape?

Tags: python, matplotlib, detection, shapes, opencv

I am doing the project to detect either the shape of watermelon is circle-like shape or oval-like shape. I'm searching it online but there is no exact answer. I don't know to use plot result, masking result or canny edge result to determine the shape.

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qUs2.jpg)

```
#plot_code
img = cv2.imread('012.jpg')
pic = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7, 7), 0)
h,w = pic.shape[:2]
im_small_long = pic.reshape((h * w, 3))
im_small_wide = im_small_long.reshape((h,w,3))
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
km.fit(im_small_long)
seg = np.asarray([(1 if i == 1 else 0)
                  for i in km.labels_]).reshape((h,w))
contours = measure.find_contours(seg, 0.5, fully_connected="high")
simplified_contours = [measure.approximate_polygon(c, tolerance=5)
                       for c in contours]
plt.figure(figsize=(5,10))
for n, contour in enumerate(simplified_contours):
    plt.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0], linewidth=2)
plt.ylim(h,0)
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
```

[plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmsM0.jpg)

```
#canny_code
img = cv2.imread('012.jpg')
pic = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7, 7), 0)
c_img = cv2.Canny(pic, 100, 200)
c_img = cv2.cvtColor(c_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
show(c_img)


#mask_code
image = cv2.imread("012.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_green = np.array([0, 50, 50])
upper_green = np.array([10, 255, 255])
greenmask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
lower_green = np.array([25, 52, 72])
upper_green = np.array([102, 255, 255])
greenmask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
greenmask=greenmask1+greenmask2
maskOpen=cv2.morphologyEx(greenmask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
maskClose=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)
greenmask=maskClose
```

[mask and canny output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrFq8.jpg)